# Json.Encode object with array string to "[ ]" instead of null

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I'm using de `Json.Encode(object)` function to convert my object to a json.

The problem is **I have a string array property (`headers`) and I want to convert it to `{ 'headers': [] }`** instead of `{ 'headers': null }` when it's empty.

My class:

```
public class BaseObject
{
    public LinkModel Links { get; set; }
}

public class LinkModel
{
    public SelfLinkModel Self { get; set; }
}

public class SelfLinkModel
{
    public string Uri { get; set; }
    public string Method { get; set; }
    public string[] Headers { get; set; }
}
```

And the Encoding:

```
string content = Json.Encode(profile);
```

To sum up, it converts to:

```
{  
    "Links":{  
        "Self":{  
            "Uri":"href",
             "Method":"GET",
             "Headers":null
        }
    }
}
```

And I want:

```
{  
    "Links":{  
        "Self":{  
            "Uri":"href",
             "Method":"GET",
             "Headers": []
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to initialise the property to an empty array. Do it in the class constructor like this:

```
public class SelfLinkModel
{
    public SelfLinkModel()
    {
        Headers = new string[0];
    }

    public string Uri { get; set; }
    public string Method { get; set; }
    public string[] Headers { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Another option to check against null before converting?

Comment: In other words, if you don't want it to serialize the property to `null`, don't let the property be `null`? ;)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Well yes, that's one way of looking at it! Of course you could build a custom serialiser, but that seems like a lot of effort for little return. :)